# rspec - handling deprecation of matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have been following the guide [everydayrailsrspec](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec)

Where one of the examples they say model specs should have validations written as:

```
it "is invalid without a lastname" do
  expect(Contact.new(lastname: nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:lastname)
end
```

Note: I know this is a random example from the entire book.

This makes sense to me. In our project we are using rspec 3 where the `have` matcher has been deprecated. Reading a bit more I see you can just add [rspec-collection_matchers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers) gem which should sort the problem.

So I have two questions:

How should the above example be written in rspec 3? I would go with

```
let(:contact) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:contact) }

it "is invalid without a name" do
  contact.name = nil
  expect(contact).to_not be_valid
end
```

My understanding tells me I should steer away from deprecated things since they won't be supported anymore. Looking at the [rspec-collection_matchers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers) gem, this seems to be the case. Is my example sufficient or is there a better way?

Second question is whether I should just use the [rspec-collection_matchers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers) gem

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you shouldn't. Such gems are usually set as a help for transitioning from old to new syntax (other example would be protected attributes and strong parameters in Rails 3/4 [there is a gem to support the former])

Comment: Do you have any input on the new syntax for the example above?

Comment: No I can't help you with syntax, but part of your question was about using a gem and wanted to clear it out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be explicit, you could write:

```
it "is invalid without a lastname" do
  contact = Contact.new(lastname: nil)
  contact.valid? # triggers validation
  expect(contact.errors[:lastname].size).to eq(1)
end
```

Comment: i think you can use `expect(contact).to be_invalid` in this case.